# Setup glut to Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, compiler-construction, glut

I want to combine OpenGL with glut with Qt creator.
I'm using Windows, my version of QT is 4.7.4, 32 bit.

I followed the tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18

I also checked some other questions of people but they didn't gave me an anwer.

The part before including glut works fine.
But when I trie to include glut it doesn't work.
The errors are:

> undefined reference to glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK

and more undefined references to glutfunctions.

I copied the glut-libraries and headers to the appropriate folders in the Minwg folder.
But I wasn't sure if this was the right folder.

Do I have to get special libraries of glut and OpenGL for Qt? And where do I have to place them?

Comment: Are you trying to combine GLUT and Qt or do you just want to use Qt Creator to develop GLUT-only programs?

Comment: I'm trying to use a GLWidget but I also wants to use GLUT in it.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to combine openGL with glut to QT creator

Why? Qt does everything GLUT does, plus many more. You don't need GLUT if you're using Qt already. What you ask for makes no sense.

#### Update due to comment

First of all: QGLWidget does everything GLUT does, plus more. The basic idea is to derive a custom Widget class from QGLWidget and override some virtual functions. *paintGL* is what you'd normally register als GLUT display function. There are also *resizeGL* and *initializeGL*.

You need resize only, if you need to reinitialize some resources after the window changed, like post-processing FBO texture attachment or such. **DO NOT**, I repeat *do not* put stuff like glViewport or projection setup there. It doesn't belong there. It belongs into the display function.

initializeGL should be used for loading textures and other one time stuff. Don't call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` there or such. This belongs into the display function as well.

So the basic gist becomes

```
class MyGLWidget : public QGLWidget 
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyGLWidget(QGLWidget *parent):
        QGLWidget(parent)
    {}

protected:
    virtual void paintGL();
    virtual void resizeGL();
    virtual void initializeGL();
}
```

Instead of glutSwapBuffers you call QGLWidget::swapBuffers at the end of the display function.

Comment: I know much of GLUT but a little of QT. But what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to get special libraries of glut and openGL for QT? And where do I have to place them?

No, but OpenGL and (optionally Glut) should be locatable in your include and library paths. That error indicates that either they are not in the include path, or you are not including them.

I second datenwolf. You do not need both Qt and Glut. If you are only using glut for the helper functions (gluLookAt, gluQuadrics) you can duplicate them fairly painlessly or simply google.